# How to add comments to a specific post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very new to rails and I don't know much about where my problem lies. Just started a few days ago and right now I am trying to add comments to a specific post. Well, technically these are not comments but more of logs added to a certain request when other people have interacted with the request like Request A has log B, log C, log D so its basically the same as a comment sytem.

I already can create the logs and display them but my main problem is showing the right logs for the right request. My logs already have the correct request id but I don't know how to get the specific logs to display for the specific request

This is my historys_controller.rb

```
class HistorysController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :require_login

  def index 
    @historys = History.where(job_order: 1)
  end

  def require_login
    unless session['user_credentials_id']
      redirect_to '/'
    end
  end
end
```

It is still set as 1 as a temporary placeholder and trying something like

```
History.where(job_order: @job_order.id)
```

and

```
History.where(job_order: params [:id])
```

does not work so what should I put there?

EDIT

history.rb

```
class History < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :job_order, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :actor, class_name: "User"
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'user_sessions#new'

  get '/sign_in', to: 'user_sessions#new', as: :sign_in
  get '/signup' => 'users#signup', as: 'signup_user'
  delete '/sign_out', to: 'user_sessions#destroy', as: :sign_out
  post '/register' => 'users#register', as: 'register_user'

  get '/users/activate/:id' => 'users#activate', as: 'activate_user'
  get '/users/deactivate/:id' => 'users#deactivate', as: 'deactivate_user'

  get '/job_order_tracking_system' => 'job_orders#dashboard', as: 'job_order_tracking_system'
  get '/job_orders/approve_job_order/:id' => 'job_orders#approve_job_order', as: 'approve_job_order'
  get '/job_orders/reject_job_order/:id' => 'job_orders#reject_job_order', as: 'reject_job_order'
  get '/job_orders/start_job_order/:id' => 'job_orders#start_job_order', as: 'start_job_order'
  get '/job_orders/done_job_order/:id' => 'job_orders#done_job_order', as: 'done_job_order'
  get '/job_orders/cancel_job_order/:id' => 'job_orders#cancel_job_order', as: 'cancel_job_order'

  resources :job_orders do
    resources :historys
  end
  resources :users
  resources :offices
  resources :user_sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :notifications do
    collection do
      post :mark_as_read
    end
  end
  # resources :historys
end
```

Comment: could you show your model configuration and params function in the controller.

Comment: Are those enough I don't really know?

Comment: can you post the `request` model, `log` model here, and also the view part how you are displaying the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want the histories for a specific job order?

Do

```
class JobOrder < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :histories
end
```

Then you can get all the related histories with

```
@job_order.histories
```

And in your view you can do somthing like...

```
<% @job_order.histories.each do |history| %>
  <%= history.name %>
  <%= history.comment %>
  <br/>
<% end %>
```

Incidentally, use the correct spelling for the plural of "history"... your controller should be `HistoriesController` Rails is smarter than you realise.

Comment: Thanks this works. I now know that rails is smarter than I realized.

Answer (score -1):

I also noticed you've got some spacing between `params` and `[:id]`. It should look this way: `params[:id]`.